# How to evaluate $\nabla \frac 1r$, $\nabla^2 \frac 1r$, $\int_S \nabla \frac 1r . ndS$

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

Let S be a smooth closed surface in a three-dimensional xyz-space, n, be the unit outward normal vector on S, and r be the distance between the origin and a point (x, y, z). Solve the following problems.

(1) Evaluate $\nabla (\frac 1r)$

(2) Evaluate $\nabla^2 (\frac 1r)$

(3) Evaluate the integral 
 $\quad \int_S \nabla (\frac 1r).ndS$ 

 when the origin is located outside S.

(4) Evaluate the integral 
 $\quad \int_S \nabla (\frac 1r).ndS$ 

 when the origin is located intside S.

First of all, I completely have no idea on what topic this problem is about.
I have tried learning divergence, differential, projection from a point to a plane, but nothing seems to  be applicable to solve this problem.

> Edited on 30th Oct 2018
>   
>  Here is my current solution
>   
>  $r = \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}$
>   
>  $\frac 1r = \frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$
>   
>   
>  Answer No. 1
>   
>  $\nabla (\frac 1r) = {\frac {\partial {\frac 1r}}{\partial x}} + {\frac {\partial {\frac 1r}}{\partial y}} + {\frac {\partial {\frac 1r}}{\partial z}} $
>   
>  $\nabla (\frac 1r) = - \frac {x \hat i + y \hat i + y \hat k}{{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}^\frac 32} $
>   
>   $\nabla (\frac 1r) = - \frac 1{r^3} {<x,y,z>}$
>   
>   
>  Answer No. 2
>   
>  $ \nabla . \nabla \frac 1r =  div \nabla \frac 1r = \nabla^2 \frac1r $
>   
>  $ \nabla^2 \frac1r  = 0$
>   
>   
>  This is as far as I've got
>   Thank you for all the helps and hints! But still I couldn't find solution to next question.

I know that on question 4 we could apply divergence theorem, but
how about question 3 when the origin is outside S?

I assume we can't apply the divergence theorem the region is not within the closed surface anymore. Is that right?

Any kind of help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what $\nabla F(x)$ means? Do you know how to find the distance between the origin and a point? Do you know what $r(x,y,z)$ is? There must be some work that you can show.

Comment: According to what I understand :
$\nabla$ means divergence, which means derivative with respect to each direction (x, y, z), the distance between the origin and a point can be found by $\sqrt { x^2 + y^2 + z^2 }$
Here is my first doubt, the $ r$ is a distance which means it's a scalar, now I think I can't apply div to a scalar value.

Comment: There is a difference between $\nabla F(x)$ and $\text{div}(F(x))=\nabla\cdot F(x)$; one is the gradient and the other is divergence.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some hints to help you get started:**

- It seems that you think $r$ is a scalar value, but it is not in the context of this problem. $r:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function that maps a point $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ to a distance $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $r$ is a hypercone in $\mathbb{R}^4$.
- The notation $\nabla f(x)$ refers to the gradient vector of $f$, $\nabla f(x)=\langle f_x,f_y,f_z\rangle$ where $f_x$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, etc...
- $\int_sf(x,y,z)dS$ is the surface (in this case closed) integral of $f$ over $S$.
- The **divergence theorem** states that $\iiint\limits_V(\nabla\cdot F)dV=\oint_S(F\cdot \hat{n})dS$

Comment: $r$ is not a sphere in $\mathbb R^4$! Though it could be thought of as a hypercone, $\{(x,y,z,r)\in\mathbb R^4\mid r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\}$. And there is nothing wrong with calling $r$ a scalar-valued _function_ (not just a number).

Comment: Another hint is that the notation $\nabla^2f$ means $\nabla\cdot(\nabla f)$, the divergence of the gradient.

Comment: @mr_e_man Ah yes, edited.

Comment: @高田航 Hi man, sorry for not being around, need to take care of some stuff, I'll try to figure it out based on the given hints, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think people in physics exchange may have a better answer, because those forlumas are not common in undergraduate math.

Bascially what you are having a headache with is coordinate transformation, you may consider your expression in spherical coordicantes. 
See, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

If you want some examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula

There are also some useful post about Del and laplas operator in both math and physics exchange.
As for the last one, I don't think you are writting it properly, it looks awfully like as if you are trying to find gauss's theorem, in that cas $n$ ought to be a vector point out of the surface.